# How do I numerically solve this type of differential equation? (Wave Equation)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, wave-equation

I'm trying to solve the wave equation numerically. I'm brand new to this and what I'm basically trying to accomplish is simulating a plucked string with fixed endpoints. How do I find the $h(x,t)$ values that satisfy the following equation?

$$\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial t^2}$$

Comment: What do you already know about finite difference schemes?

Comment: Nothing. :P But I can look into it!

Comment: The simplest thing you can do which is still "reasonable" is forward Euler with centered differences for the second derivative in space. Consider times $t_n=n \Delta t$ and spatial values $x_i=i\Delta x$. Then your state is $(h(n,i),v(n,i))$. You update by $h(n+1,i)=h(n,i)+\Delta t v(n,i)$ and $v(n+1,i)=v(n,i)+\Delta t \frac{v(n,i+1)-2v(n,i)+v(n,i-1)}{\Delta x^2}$. This scheme is very bad for several reasons, but much better schemes have a similar form.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I was thinking of something like this, I just didn't know how to approach it. Appreciate the help (: I'll look into other methods later, but I'll stick with this for simplicity's sake.

Comment: A warning: one reason this scheme is bad is that your time step must be very small compared to the space step to avoid nonphysical blowups.

Comment: ...I made a silly error. You should have $v(n+1,i)=v(n,i)+\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2} (h(n,i+1)-2h(n,i)+h(n,i-1))$; the spatial difference is in $h$ not $v$.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways, but I'll give you one. From writing out the Taylor expansions of $f(x+\Delta x)$ and $f(x-\Delta x)$ you can show that we can approximate the second derivative in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $$\frac{h(x+\Delta x,t)-2h(x,t)+h(x-\Delta x,t)}{(\Delta x)^2}=h_{xx}(x,t)+O(\Delta x^2)$$ So, substituting in we get $$\frac{h(x+\Delta x,t)-2h(x,t)+h(x-\Delta x,t)}{(\Delta x)^2}=c^2\left[\frac{h(x,t+\Delta t)-2h(x,t)+h(x,t-\Delta t)}{(\Delta t)^2}\right] + O(\Delta x^2, \Delta t^2)$$
Now pick some $T>0$, $N,M\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $x_n=n\Delta x$, $n=0,1,2,...,N$ and $t_k=k\Delta t$, $k=0,1,2,...,M$ where $\Delta x=1/N$ and $\Delta t=T/M$ (You haven't given boundary conditions for the PDE, so I assumed that $0\leq x\leq1$). Then let $$h^k_n=h(x_n,t_k)=h(n\Delta x, k\Delta t),\quad0\leq k\leq M,\;0\leq n\leq N$$
So, using this notation and the equation above we can solve for the next step in time by:
$$h_n^{k+1}=2h_n^k-h_n^{k-1}+\frac{(\Delta t)^2}{c^2(\Delta x)^2}\left[h_{n+1}^k-2h_n^k+h_{n-1}^k\right]$$
Note here that we let $O(\Delta x^2, \Delta t^2)\rightarrow0$. Then from this we can build our finite difference grid.

Based on Uranix's suggestion, it is definitely worth noting that to obtain convergence for this finite difference scheme we require that $\Delta t\leq c\Delta x$; which is called the CFL condition. (Note that if you look it up it will appear as $\Delta t\leq\frac{\Delta x}{c}$, but this is referring to the general wave equation $h_{tt}=c^2h_{xx}$ rather than $h_{xx}=c^2h_{tt}$ as you have).

**However,**  we must note that this is a recurrence relation that depends on the last two times (time $k+1$ depends on time $k$ and $k-1$) and the two space positions on either side of $h_n^k$ ($h_{n-1}^k$ and $h_{n+1}^k$). So to build anything, we need to use the boundary and initial conditions to get started.

Comment: You have both $\Delta t$ in the last equation. Also I suggest adding some conditions on the timestep $\Delta t$ (CFL).

Comment: Good call! Thanks.

Comment: I managed to use this and get the result I was looking for. Thank you so much! :)